# Amazon S3 files sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my project there is a need for creating share link for external users without aws user from my researching found out a couple ways for doing so

1. Bucket policy based on tag
2. Lambda that creates sign url every time some user request the file

The question is what is the best practice for doing so
I need the download to be available until the user sharing the file stopes it
Thank guys for any answers

Comment: try using s3 presigned url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html, you can make this URL valid for desired amount of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the AWS SDK, you can use Amazon S3 Pre-sign functionality. You can perform this task in any of the supported programming languages (Java, JS, Python, etc).

The following code shows how to sign an object via the Amazon S3 Java V2 API.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.time.Duration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.GetObjectPresignRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.model.PresignedGetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.presigner.S3Presigner;
import software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils;
// snippet-end:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.import]

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectPresignedUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetObjectPresignedUrl <bucketName> <keyName> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
                "    keyName - a key name that represents a text file. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 2) {
           System.out.println(USAGE);
           System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        getPresignedUrl(presigner, bucketName, keyName);
        presigner.close();

    }
      // snippet-start:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.main]
       public static void getPresignedUrl(S3Presigner presigner, String bucketName, String keyName ) {

        try {
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
                    GetObjectRequest.builder()
                            .bucket(bucketName)
                            .key(keyName)
                            .build();

            GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest =  GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                            .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                            .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                             .build();

            // Generate the presigned request
            PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
                    presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

            // Log the presigned URL
            System.out.println("Presigned URL: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) presignedGetObjectRequest.url().openConnection();
            presignedGetObjectRequest.httpRequest().headers().forEach((header, values) -> {
                values.forEach(value -> {
                    connection.addRequestProperty(header, value);
                });
            });

            // Send any request payload that the service needs (not needed when isBrowserExecutable is true)
            if (presignedGetObjectRequest.signedPayload().isPresent()) {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                try (InputStream signedPayload = presignedGetObjectRequest.signedPayload().get().asInputStream();
                     OutputStream httpOutputStream = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                    IoUtils.copy(signedPayload, httpOutputStream);
                }
            }

            // Download the result of executing the request
            try (InputStream content = connection.getInputStream()) {
                System.out.println("Service returned response: ");
                IoUtils.copy(content, System.out);
            }

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        // snippet-end:[presigned.java2.getobjectpresigned.main]
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it this way but as I understand Pre-sign URLs have a limited life span and for my functionality i need the link to be alive as long as the user wants it to live

Comment: YOu are correct - you can define the time in which the link is active

Comment: there is maybe another way for solving this problem?

Comment: You can define a custom solution to this where you ask user for how long they need this link, based on the user input, you generate your pre-sign url

Comment: and if the user doesn't know for how long he wants the link to be active? is there a way for solving this?